# Nginx + php5-fpm not respecting set_time_limit

Tags: php, nginx

PHP set_time_limit doesn't work even if it is smaller than other limits.
For example, the following code will run to the end:

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(5);
    sleep(10);
    echo "Did not work!";
?>
```

I know about `request_terminate_timeout` and `fastcgi_read_timeout`, but these are not relevant in this case.

**How can i make nginx+php5-fpm respect time limit i'm setting?**

I have pretty much default configurigation for both:

**Nginx:**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

**PHP5-FPM:**

```
Default config, no limit specified (request_terminate_timeout = 0)
```

**PHP:**

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

Although in [php-fpm documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php) says about `request_terminate_timeout`: `"This option should be used when the 'max_execution_time' ini option does not stop script execution for some reason."`

I'd still like to find a solution to that problem...

**Note:** I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Nginx 1.4.6 and PHP 5.5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the manual on [set_time_limit()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. **is not included** when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running.

This applies also to the `sleep()` command, as also mentioned in the comments in the manual. So the time during sleeping is not even counted. After your sleep command at the end of the script, the accumulated time is almost zero.

You can try if your time settings works by for example running endless loop and measuring the time taken from start to the end of the script.

Comment: As it seems you are correct. With `while(true);` it works as expected :)